# jQuery widget function not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, jquery-widgets

**Update:**
Sorry for the lengthy stupid question. It was a problem with my selector. Ignore post!

I have a widget that is having public functions. that I normally am able to call like:

```
$("#mygrid").myGrid( "MyFunction", args );
```

**Problem:**

But in some cases the function is not getting called.

*Here are some trivia*

- My widget is derived from another (base)widget I created.
- The same function works when called for the base widget
- The function is not overridden in the child widget.
- The same function works for another child widget of the same parent
  with the same piece of code I mentioned earlier except the name of
  the widget and the DOM element.

*Now, here are some important information.*

A similar function in the problem widget works and when I stepped inside the call, I found a difference in both the calls in the following function in *jquery-ui.js*:

```
$.widget.bridge = function( name, object ) {
    var fullName = object.prototype.widgetFullName || name;
    $.fn[ name ] = function( options ) {
        var isMethodCall = typeof options === "string",
            args = slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            returnValue = this;

        // allow multiple hashes to be passed on init
        options = !isMethodCall && args.length ?
            $.widget.extend.apply( null, [ options ].concat(args) ) :
            options;

        if ( isMethodCall ) {
            this.each(function() {
                var methodValue,

 // Rest of the code.
```

Here, For my function that is not getting called, it won't enter in that `this.each`. when I checked the `this` pointer, there was a difference.
For the function that is getting called, the content of `this` is like the following:

```
0: div#myGrid
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#mygrid"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

But for the function that is NOT getting called, the first item and the length attribute was missing.

```
context: document
selector: "#mygrid"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

What Could be the problem?

Comment: You might want to add some code that shows how you're invoking that jquery-ui code.  We can tell it's a context issue, but we need to see higher in the execution stack to see how this function is being called.  You can say that both are the same, but something is different in your code.  You haven't shown that.  And it's probably something you don't see.

Comment: You were right :( case sensitivity of selector!